# Add new custom product attribute to invoice in Magento 1

Tags: php, magento, customization

I create a  custom attribute seller_id and I added to Attribute sets too,I want to display seller name in **template** as well as **admin side invoice**.How to get the seller name from seller_id ? How I can do this?

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/38612059/3604226 Hope it helps you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add new product attribute to invoice in Magento 1.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38611808/add-new-product-attribute-to-invoice-in-magento-1-9)

Comment: I want to add seller name admin side invoice,can you tell me How ?